# Map Droplist item to complextype using Glass.Mapper

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper

I have created two Sitecore templatates MenuItem and MainNavigation.
I have created two interfaces wich are based on these templates:

```cs
 [SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{C824E484-F4A6-475C-AFAF-308FF4BBA5A9}", AutoMap = true)]
public interface IMenuItem
{
    string Title { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<IMenuItem> SubMenuItems { get; set; }
}
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{68947CC0-7658-4188-889D-4E88B84F3BC2}", AutoMap = true)]
public interface IMainNavigation
{        
    IMenuItem MenuHeaderItem { get; set; }

    IEnumerable<IMenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping MenuItems from an MultiList is working.
The mapping MenuHeaderItem from an Droplist is not. 
In the template I have provided an query in the datasource so only MenuItems can be selected.

How can I make this mapping work?

I've tried v4.0.5.54 and now I have updated to version 4.2.1.188

Comment: Your models look correct, although you don't _need_ to set the `InferType` attribute... double check your template that the field is named exactly `MenuHeaderItem` without any spaces in the name.

Comment: I have removed the InferType attribute and copy paste the property name from the template.  But the mapping still doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found the answer myself. In the template I have to use sitecore type **Droplink** instead of **DropList**.

Droplist only stores the selected item name as a string. Droplink also stores the GUID.

Answer (score -1):

What if you try to put this Annotation (see below) for the property that is not being populated:

```
[SitecoreField(FieldName = "MenuHeaderItem", FieldType = SitecoreFieldType.Droplist)]
```